# Server Client multithread

Tags: java, eclipse, sockets, server

I'm doing my assignment with Chat Server-client. Here is how i start server

```
public static void StartServer(){
    // Create socket
    try {
        serversocket = new ServerSocket(ServerPort);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        isError = true;
        ERRORCODE = "ERROR! Cannot create a new socket! " + e.getMessage();
        return;
    }

    // A new thread to wait for connection
    Thread TH_Wait4Connection = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            while(true){
                String ERRORHere = "-1"; // To specify whre the Errors are
                try {
                    Connection = new Socket();
                    Connection = serversocket.accept();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    ERRORCODE =  ERRORHere + " : " + e.getMessage();
                    return;
                }

                // Another Thread to handle a connection
                try {
                    ERRORHere = "1";
                    Thread Client = new Thread(new ConnHandler(Connection));
                    ERRORHere = "2";
                    threadList.add(Client);
                    ERRORHere = "3";
                    Client.start();
                    ERRORHere = "4";
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    ERRORCODE = ERRORHere + " : " + e.getMessage();
                    return;
                }
                try {Thread.sleep(10);} catch (Exception e) {}
            } // End why loop
        } // End run()
    };

    TH_Wait4Connection.start();
}
```

When i debug in eclipse, my clients can connect to server and everything is fine, server creates threads and no exception catched. But if i Run, it goes into the last catch and my ERRORCODE

```
ERRORCODE = ERRORHere + " : " + e.getMessage();
```

is

```
1 : 6 > 4
```

What are those errors? And how to fix it?

Thank for read.

## Update class ConnHandler

```
public class ConnHandler implements Runnable{

    public ConnHandler(Socket Connection) throws Exception{

        InputStream IS = Connection.getInputStream();   
        byte[] InData =  new byte[1024];
        int bytesCount = IS.read(InData);
        // Remove first 6 bytes
        byte[] NewInData = Arrays.copyOfRange(InData, 6, bytesCount);
    }

public void run(){}
}
```

Comment: what does ConnHandler class do, i think based on "1" then it crashes while instantiating from ConnHandler, right?

Comment: Thanks for reply. ConnHandler updated. I dont know where is wrong in my code, this class is so simple, i think. And it crashes just when in Run App, nothing happens when i run Debug.

Comment: oops i think i found my problem. i try to remove this line    byte[] NewInData = Arrays.copyOfRange(InData, 6, bytesCount);    bytesCount is out of InData array range. but I wonder why there are no errors when i run Debug. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is this line in ConnHandler:

`byte[] NewInData = Arrays.copyOfRange(InData, 6, bytesCount);`

When calling this line bytesCount is 4. Since argument **FROM** is bigger then argument **TO** (6 > 4), it throws an IllegalArgumentException. [See here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/arrays_copyofrange_short.htm) for more information about this method.

In general it is **not advisable** to catch the type Exception instead of the subtypes in different catch-blocks. Your current implementation could hide unchecked Exceptions. Further if you catch the subtypes, you will know what type occurred (without manually checking) and debug faster, like in your current case.

Comment: thanks thanks thanks. finally i found it . thank so much